# How to return a name of element incase of error in protractor?

Tags: xpath, typescript, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to handle various error scenarios while finding an element using protractor in typescript. 
Here is how I am doing it:

```
textBoxA = this.findElementBy(locator.XPATH,"//input[@formname='name']");
```

Here `//input[@formname='name']` is my xpath for the element.

If the xpath is given wrong, then protractor gives me error like `no element found using xpath...` and probably also the file in which the spec failed etc which many npm reporters also report.

But, instead of that I want the name of element that failed like in the above instance, I want `textBoxA` to appear somewhere in the log so that it is easy to debug in case I have numerous specs.

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: I know the program first reads the right hand side of equals and then the left. So, if an incorrect Xpath is provided, the code breaks there itself and is unable to move further. Hence, textBoxA is virtually impossible to reproduce. But, some other turnaround is always appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below 2 approach for this:

1. Better approach for this would be to implement `function(err){}` whenever you invoke any action of any element. Here you can handle the error like:

> ElementNotFound, NoSuchWindowsError or ElementStaleError etc...

2. Another approach could be to implement a wrapper when element is created. For example:
   For example:

   `var nameElem = findElement(by.id('name'), 'Name Element');`

findElement function definition:

```
findElement: function(elemCss, elemName){
    element(elemCss).isPresent().then(function(value){
        if (present) {
            /* element exists */
        } else {
            /* element doesn't exist, use elemName and record anywhere in your custom log */
        }
    })
}
```